# ASP.Net Core/Blazor Authentication using Authenticator app

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor

I was investigating passwordless authentication for my new Blazor app and most of the examples point to Email based authentication like medium.com authentication.

- User registers
- Authentication email sent to the email id
- User clicks the link in the email to login

Is there a similar process flow where instead of email the Authenticator app is used. Like

- User registers
- QR code is generated based on email id + key - similar to email link
- User scans the QR code and adds to Authenticator app
- User login using the code

All future login - user enters the email id and either notification is sent to Authenticator app or code is entered to login.

Comment: Well, the link isn't really a login link-- it's an e-mail confirmation link, which may / may not log you in when you click it.  My question would be-- once you log in with your APP, what's to stop anyone else from just entering your e-mail and getting into your account for free?

Comment: it is not an email confirmation link. It is actually a login confirmation link (paasswordless login). Not sure what you mean by "once you login" question. I am talking about the login process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GoogleAuthenticator` nuget package to implement an authenticator app-based login. You can do something like this to verify the user.

```
var accountSecretKey = $"{twoFactorSecretCode}-{user.Email}";
var twoFactorAuthenticator = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
var result = twoFactorAuthenticator
    .ValidateTwoFactorPIN(accountSecretKey, profileViewModel.UserInputCode);
```

You can find more details about the implementation [here](https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-implement-2fa-with-aspnet-core-without-identity/)